# CSS Grid place items from right to left

Tags: css, position, css-grid

I am working on a web application that has a member list. The quantity of member will come dynamically from the server. I want to show each member's info in a grid of four columns.
Is it possible to **dynamically place each item from right to left using Css Grid?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use `direction` property:

```
.container
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25vw 25vw 25vw 25vw;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh; /* Your number of rows */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: Wow That was pretty simple. Thank you :)

Comment: But this changes also all child content right to left.

Comment: Yes, @elano7, but you can also restore the expected direction in children by using `direction: rtl` on them.